# ASP.NET Core map query params to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have `get` request with folowing params:

```
?
idoperator=and&
filtervalue0=2&
filtercondition0=EQUAL&
filteroperator0=1&
filterdatafield0=id&
entityTypeoperator=and&
filtervalue1=0&
filtercondition1=EQUAL&
filteroperator1=1&
filterdatafield1=entityType&

filterGroups[0][field]=id&
filterGroups[0][filters][0][label]=2&
filterGroups[0][filters][0][value]=2&
filterGroups[0][filters][0][condition]=EQUAL&
filterGroups[0][filters][0][operator]=or&
filterGroups[0][filters][0][field]=id&
filterGroups[0][filters][0][type]=numericfilter&

filterGroups[1][field]=entityType&
filterGroups[1][filters][0][label]=0&
filterGroups[1][filters][0][value]=0&
filterGroups[1][filters][0][condition]=EQUAL&
filterGroups[1][filters][0][operator]=or&
filterGroups[1][filters][0][field]=entityType&
filterGroups[1][filters][0][type]=numericfilter&

filterscount=2&
groupscount=0&
pagenum=0&
pagesize=20&
recordstartindex=0&
recordendindex=20&
_=1486647909033"
```

And I'm trying to map request to `FilterContaier` entity but `FilterGroups` is null after deserialization. Is there way to debug binding process?

```
public class FilterContaier
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "filterscount")]
    public int FiltersCount { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "groupscount")]
public int GroupsCount { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "pagenum")]
public int PageNum { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "pagesize")]
public int PageSize { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "filterGroups")]
public List<JqxGridFilterGroup> FilterGroups { get; set; }

}

public class JqxGridFilterGroup
{
[FromQuery(Name = "field")]
public string Field { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "filters")]
public List<JqxGridFilter> Filters { get; set; }

}

public class JqxGridFilter
{
[FromQuery(Name = "label")]
public string Label { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "value")]
public string Value { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "condition")]
public string Condition { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "operator")]
public string Operator { get; set; }

[FromQuery(Name = "type")]
public string Type { get; set; }
}
```